# Get a child div to appear above absolutely positioned parent

Tags: css, html

Is it possible to get a div, inside an absolutely position div, to show above it's parent, but aligned to it so the top of the child div is square with the bottom of the parent div and the child div is now above other parents on the same level as it's own parent ?

e.g I have a page with square blocks on it, say four rows of four. Inside each block, is a child element which shows on rollover, aligned to the bottom of the parent block and over the top of blocks adjacent to the parent block.

The parent blocks are absolutely positioned

http://jsfiddle.net/W3Kaq/

```
<div id="container">
<div class="parent">
Some Box
<div class="child">
    Some Child Box
</div>
</div>
<div class="parent" style="left:140px;">
Some Box
<div class="child">
    Some Child Box
</div>
</div>
<div class="parent" style="top:140px;">
Some Box
<div class="child">
    Some Child Box
</div>
</div>
<div class="parent" style="top:140px; left:140px;">
Some Box
<div class="child">
    Some Child Box
</div>
</div>
</div>

#container {
position: relative;
}

.parent {
background: #444;
color: #fff;
display: block;
height: 100px;
padding: 10px;
position: absolute;
width: 100px;
z-index: 2;
}

.child {
background: #777;
display: none;    
height: 300px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 3;
}

.parent:hover .child {
display: block;
}
```

Comment: Please show us your HTML...it should be simple enough.

Comment: If the parent DIVs are all at the same z-index level then they will be layered in the order they appear in the code with the later ones on top of the earlier ones, irrespective of what's inside of them. Ultimately any child elements obtain the z-index of their parent when compared to any elements outside of the parent, however within their parent the z-index applies as you'd imagine amongst other elements inside that parent.

Comment: OK so maybe on hover, I need to increase the z-index of the parent ?

Comment: No, just remove the z-index of the parent. It's still not entirely clear what it is you are trying to so. Is it something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/W3Kaq/1/ ?

Comment: @Paulie_D removing the z-index does not work, however if I set the parents z-index to 999 on rollover, it works :)

Comment: @Paulie_D you got the idea but I can't take away the absolute positioning or z-index of the parent because of how the page works. Just upping the z-index of the hovered parent produces the required effect, thanks guys for the help

Answer (score 0):

Use `z-index` on your child div and set a positive number on it e.g. 999.

Also don't forget to add `position:absolute` to your child div also for `z-index` to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

use this css. add overflow = hidden to parent and add z-index like 20 + so you get child div apper.

```
#container {
position: relative;
}

.parent {
background: #444;
color: #fff;
display: block;
height: 100px;
padding: 10px;
position: absolute;
width: 100px;
z-index: 2;
overflow:hidden
 }

.child {
background: #777;
display: none;    
height: 300px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 3;
}

.parent:hover .child {
display: block;
z-index:0;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the z-index for the parent and this will work. See [This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W3Kaq/2/)

```
.parent {
    background: #444;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;

}
```

Not sure if this is will affect other things in your code.